# Joomla problems with utf8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, joomla

I´ve got this error installing joomla 3.6.5.

> 1115 Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4' SQL=CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   `jm34_utf8_conversion` ( `converted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)
>   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 DEFAULT
>   COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

A person told me is a problem with mysql version. I've got 5.1.71 and I should have 5.5.3. Another one told me that I can with 5.1 but I must change utf8mb4 to utf8 to use the statements for that database. how can i do?
Another me told me that 5.1.71 is an old version and my hosting must change to 5.5.3.

What can  I do without updating mysql?

Answer (score 0):

5.1 can handle utf8.  5.5.3 is needed for utf8mb4.

utf8mb4 is a superset of utf8.  It adds on Emoji and some more Chinese characters.

You should update from the *old* 5.1.  Complain to the Hosting service.  Or move to another service.

You could switch to utf8 (with 5.1) *if* you don't need Emoji or Chinese.

Comment: How can I  switch to utf8 (with 5.1) if you don't need Emoji or Chinese?

Comment: `VARBINARY(...)` or `BLOB` will work in place of `VARTEXT(...)` or `TEXT`.  (This will make more work in the future when you do get past 5.1.)

Comment: But  must i change all the sql sentencies?

Comment: No SQL queries need to be changed.